# Cannot connect mySQL 5.6 to glassfish 2.1.1 using mysql connector 5.1.36 Class name is wrong or classpath is not set

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish, mysql-5.6, glassfish-2.x

On glassfish when I'm trying to ping my conncetion pool an error is occuring:  Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource

I pasted the mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar in all those paths:
glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
glassfish/lib
and
glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/classes

Datasource Classname: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
Resource Type: Java.sql.DataSource

On additional Properties: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name

But it seems like it is not loading the connector, I can't find where is the problem.

Is it possible that glassfish 2.1.1 is not compatible with mysql 5.6 and needs an older version?

Unfortunately, the project I'm working on runs only on glassfish 2.1.1 :(

Comment: locate glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log and paste it